# PHP Upload Failing

Tags: php, file-upload

Whenever I am uploading any file it says,

File is an image - image/png.Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

I am using post method and enctype="multipart/form-data". My image file is also proper.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $target_dir = "pics/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                echo "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
     }
?>





<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="usr">Select image to upload:</label>
                  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="usr">URL:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" name="url">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Reset</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: Looks like the generic W3Schools code http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp which I can't see failing here, unless there's something you haven't done properly, like change something in the form, or checked if that folder you're wanting to upload to, has the proper permissions to write to it. Check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Added form code also

Answer (score 1):

Your file cannot be moved.

- Check the path to move to
- Check the permissions of the directory
- Check your access to the `tmp` directory

You use a relative path: `$target_dir = "pics/";`

Change your path to:

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pics/';
```

Comment: Path is correct. I have given 777 access to that upload.php file, and even tried `$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pics/';` . But still it is not working.